# Using nested property string with automapper MapFrom

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'd like to use a string that represents some navigation properties on my class for the mapping. I've also tried converting the string to a PropertyExpression but have not been able to wire it up correctly.
Is it possible to use automapper in the way demonstrated below?

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestClass>()
       .ForMember(targetField, "prop1.nested1.nested2";
});
```

Comment: Why do you want a string with properties? What if the property name will change, you get runtime error

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/88a7c788124c184ca570d21f4dda4da32cb17a3b/src/AutoMapper/Internal/ExpressionFactory.cs#L24